# Error after updating react-scripts in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I'm getting this error after upgrading react-scripts to ^3.0.0 in my node app --

```
 FAIL  src/components/App/index.test.js
    ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'date-fns/addDays' from 'date-fns-utils.js'

    However, Jest was able to find:
        './index.css'
        './index.js'
        './index.test.js'

    You might want to include a file extension in your import, or update your 'moduleFileExtensions', which is currently ['web.js', 'js', 'web.ts', 'ts', 'web.tsx', 'tsx', 'json', 'web.jsx', 'jsx', 'node'].

    See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulefileextensions-array-string

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:230:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/material-ui-pickers/utils/date-fns-utils.js:8:39)
```

I've manually installed and updated `date-fns`, and had trouble finding any breaking changes directly associated with this problem. (Pretty new to npm and react).

Comment: Is it working after you manually installed date-fns

Comment: Still not no, I thought that would work but it did not.

Comment: @MonikaMangal Any ideas about why this may be?

Comment: No idea. Whenever I get these type of issues I manually install them and they work.

Comment: may be try deleting the node-modules folder and npm install again